# How do I stop chart js from auto rescaling the y axis upon calling chart.update()?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have created a graph which is scaled according the value selected on the first slider.
[image]
[image]

As you can see in the second picture, the first slider is set to 50 and the values are all halved. My problem is that chart js auto rescales the y axis whenever `chart.update()` is called (which is called whenever I drag the slider).
How do I disable this?

Answer (score 1):

When creating the chart, you could define `min` and `max` options for [`yAxes.ticks`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#tick-options). This may be hard-coded value or you may derive them from the chart data.

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    max: 350,
    min: 0
  }
}]
```